# How To Make Slash Commmand In discord.py

Tags: discord.py

my code :

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord_slash import SlashCommand
from discord_slash import SlashContext

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="#", intents=discord.Intents.all())
slash = SlashCommand(bot, sync_commands=True)

class Slash(commands.Cog):
  def __init__(self, bot):
    self.bot = bot


  @slash.slash(name="test", description="hello!")
  async def hello(self, ctx: SlashContext):
    await ctx.respond()
    await ctx.send(content="HELLO!")

def setup(bot):
  bot.add_cog(Slash(bot))
```

the code runs without any errors, but the slash command isn't there. can you fix it?

and I want my library to submit the slash command to make it easier

Comment: I don't recommend you to use slash commands, as Discord got Problems with "wrong" slash commands, so those which aren't in the menu that opens when you type "/". Maybe your message will also be completely blocked so you got the animation like you got a message cooldown.

Answer (score 2):

When you create a slash command in a cog you need to use:

```
@cog_ext.cog_slash()
```

instead of:

```
@slash.slash()
```

You will also need the cog extension at the start of your code:

```
from discord_slash import cog_ext
```